# Disable future date selection for Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with date input, and I want to prevent users from selecting future dates:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.month').datepicker({
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
       endDate: '+1d',
     });
    });
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
    <input type="text" readonly="" id="sale_from" placeholder="Click & Select From Date" value="" size="16" class="form-control month">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
    <input type="text" readonly="" id="sale_to" placeholder="Click & Select To Date" size="16" class="form-control month">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code work just fine :  http://jsfiddle.net/vh1oknf7/173/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki yes its working in fiddle, but why it is not working in my local :(.

Comment: Not sure, but i'm sure the problem is not in the posted code ...

Answer (score 2):

> Well I see your code is perfect except the syntax error(, after
>   `endDate` parameter but it wont affect anything)

So please check the `datepicker` JS you are using as there are multiple `Bootstrap datepickers` are available.

I have provided the working demo, please copy the same plugins to your app and test it out.

```js
 $('.month').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            endDate: '+1d'
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
            <input type="text" readonly="" id="sale_from" placeholder="Click & Select From Date" value="" size="16" class="form-control month">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
            <input type="text" readonly="" id="sale_to" placeholder="Click & Select To Date" size="16" class="form-control month">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So why this answer? This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: It shows that the code is working fine but there might be issue with imports. May be older version, I have provided the working plugins version for the same.

Comment: _but there might be issue with imports_ that still a comment not an answer.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I understand what you are trying to say but if user gets an working demo of his code it will be beneficial for him right ?

Comment: @Prakash you are right my bootstrap date picker was outdated one but i found it before your comment :P anyhow thank you soo much.

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem then you can accept it. If it helped you then you can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, instead of endDate you should use maxDate parameter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.month').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            maxDate: new Date, minDate: new Date(2007, 6, 12) 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
            <input type="text" readonly="" id="sale_from" placeholder="Click & Select From Date" value="" size="16" class="form-control month">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
            <input type="text" readonly="" id="sale_to" placeholder="Click & Select To Date" size="16" class="form-control month">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: issue solved it is due to my bootstrap date picker was outdated i updated it and it is working now :). thank you.